# gRPC server long response times over ethernet

Tags: performance, go, server, grpc

I was testing client-server connection with gRPC client written in C# and a bunch of servers (written in c++, C#, rust and go). As I was testing it locally everything went okay (average GO response around 0.12ms) but when I test it over local network it gets really slow, like REALLY slow. Average time goes to 40ms per request! 
To be clear: I am using a simple HelloWorld proto with simplest connection possible. Other servers get about 1ms per request but Go - around 40ms.

My Go server code:

```
 package main

import (
    "context"
    pb "descriptions"
    "log"
    "net"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"
)

type server struct{}

// SayHello implements helloworld.GreeterServer
func (s *server) SayHello(ctx context.Context, in *pb.HelloRequest) (*pb.HelloReply, error) {
    //log.Printf("Received: %v", in.Name)
    return &pb.HelloReply{Message: ""}, nil
}

func main() {
    //  lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", port)
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:50051")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }
    s := grpc.NewServer()
    log.Printf("Server listening on: " + lis.Addr().String())
    pb.RegisterGreeterServer(s, &server{})
    if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
    }
}
```

I do not suspect that it is client side issiue because it works well with other servers. Have anyone had the same issiue with golang? Please let me know! 
I was also thinking if that might be like HTTP 1.1 issue but gRPC supports HTTP2 so I suspect it is already used when running this code.

Comment: If you use netperf to test the local network, which are the results?

Comment: Netperf? haven't heard about that. I will check tomorrow asap and let You know

Comment: How exactly are you testing on the ethernet? I am just asking out of curiosity as I don't know how it is done.
Although I can't see anything obviously wrong on your Go code.

Comment: I have a grpc client that sends hello packets to server. I am timing each packet sent to the server, just a casual "timer on, send and receive, timer off". For all other servers it works well but on GO server it is a total crap. Like it is not casching the client but it it like he connects as a new client every time or something

Answer (score 0):

According to the benchmark [here](https://performance-dot-grpc-testing.appspot.com/explore?dashboard=5652536396611584), Go and C++ shouldn't have such big difference (over ethernet). Could you please file an issue in the grpc-go repo, https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/new? And it will be very helpful if you can provide more context about how client side works. Thanks!

Comment: Will do. Thbk You for your answer!